# Laravel collection count() takes too long

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a contacts table and a contact_list table, a contact_list has many contacts, contacts table has a *is_active* field.

[image]

to get the number of active contacts for a contact_list i use the query builder as follows:

`$contact_list->contacts()->where('is_active', 1)->count();`

if the number of contacts is too big the query takes too long.
is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried setting an index on your `is_active` column? These usually help speed up requests. Considering you're doing a count, it really shouldn't be long at all as I can run a count on a DB with over 1,000,000 and get it within just a few seconds. If you SSH in to the box, log in to your mysql and run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` so you can see exactly what's being run and how long it's taken.

Comment: ^ What he said. Also consider making `is_active` a boolean field in your migration, no need for `int`

Comment: Thanks guys, i added the index and it's working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

as I can see you want to optimize the performance of your request.

to achieve that you should use eager-loading, so your new request should be like below:

```
$contactList = App\ContactList::with(['contacts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_active', 1);
}])->count();
```

For more information about how Laravel implement eager-loading please check the link of documentation: [eager-loading documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: I set an index for is_active and it's working, thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

With InnoDB COUNT() works slowly for tables with million rows.
That's a problem with count() as the InnoDB engine locks the table per row, and if the table is being changed on a regular bases the count() function is not trivial.

The Eloquent ORM doesn't differenciatie between InnoDB or MyISAM so the count() process always triggers something like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS aggregate FROM table`.

If you change the query with this one `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table` you will realize that the count() process is way faster.

So in Laravel that would be reduced to something like:

```
Model::select(DB:raw('count(1)'))->first();
```

Or in your case

```
$contact_list->contacts()->select()->where('is_active', 1)->count();
```